# How to get rid of the missing left parenthesis in oracle apex?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, dml

**My problem:** I am trying to create a table named *User_T* in Oracle apex.

I can't get rid of this displaying error... I don't know why. I've already checked my codes a couple of times.

```
CREATE TABLE User_T(
    IdUser NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL,
    FirstName   VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
    LastName    VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Email   VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    UserName    VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    UserPassword    VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
    CreatedAt   VARCHAR2(30),
    UpdatedAt   VARCHAR(30),
    Enabled    CHAR(10) CHECK,
    CONSTRAINT IdUser_PK PRIMARY KEY(IdUser)
);
```

[image]

Comment: Remove the `CHECK` keyword (or add a proper check constraint)

Answer (score 3):

You have a `CHECK` keyword without specifying a constraint.

Either remove it:

```sql
CREATE TABLE User_T(
    IdUser NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL,
    FirstName   VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
    LastName    VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Email   VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    UserName    VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    UserPassword    VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
    CreatedAt   VARCHAR2(30),
    UpdatedAt   VARCHAR(30),
    Enabled    CHAR(10),                        -- Remove the CHECK
    CONSTRAINT IdUser_PK PRIMARY KEY(IdUser)
);
```

else, specify the constraint:

```sql
CREATE TABLE User_T(
    IdUser NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL,
    FirstName   VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
    LastName    VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Email   VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    UserName    VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    UserPassword    VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
    CreatedAt   VARCHAR2(30),
    UpdatedAt   VARCHAR(30),
    Enabled    CHAR(10) CHECK (Enabled IN ('Foo       ', 'Bar       ')),
    CONSTRAINT IdUser_PK PRIMARY KEY(IdUser)
);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=30bb51011bc645dec0a75f221ec83446)*